# What's wrong this jQuery code? (Img height)

Tags: jquery

I want this:

If the img height is bigger than 187px it get a padding-top attribute with individual pixel.(current img height -(minus) 187px) .

The code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".tabbed-area .box-wrap .box img").load(function() {
            $imgh = $(this).height();
            if($imgh < 187)
            {   
                $real = $imgh - 187;
                $(this).css("padding-top", $real);
            }
         });

        });
```

Comment: @Cattla you can have negative padding

Comment: That exactly are you trying to achieve? Make all images  the same 
"height" (and max 187px) hiding the top?

Comment: !......no response......!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying *"img height is bigger than 187px"*

while you have a check for the less than `<`, that could be the issue change to this:

```
if($imgh > 187)
```

Comment: I think this was a misunderstanding and in fact is "smaller than" because it would not make sense this way ...

Comment: yeah it is getting confusing, that is why i quoted the line.